# Sidecasting to other known superclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class inheriting from two other (Virtual) classes.
Let's call my two superclasses A and B. I can have objects that only inherit from A, objects that only inherit from B, and objects that inherit from both A and B.
Now, optimally, I'd like to have a container somewhere that holds objects known to inherit from both: Apologies for the C/Java syntax mashup, but this could look something like follows: `std::vector<? : A, B>`. Now, this doesn't exist, but as it turns out the class holding my container mainly uses the "A" functionality of those classes, which is why I'm currently using `std::vector<A*>`.

However, at one particular place somewhere else in my code, in a different place, that same vector gets accessed, but with the intention of using the "B" functionality.

While I personally *know* that I've made sure that all instances added to my vector extend from both A and B, the compiler does not. That makes it obviously difficult for me to access that B functionality.

So therefore, my question is as follows: How do I "sidecast" something from A to B? I have a pointer to `A`, with the dynamic type of something LIKE `C` (ie, inhereting from A and B - but not necessarily a SPECIFIC C), but want to get a pointer to `B`, obviously without changing the dynamic type.

dynamic_cast does the job, but I assume that's an ugly way of doing it. Any better ideas?

Comment: `While I personally know that I've made sure that all instances added to my vector extend from both A and B, the compiler does not. ` Why not tell it then by just storing the instance of `C` which inherits from both A and B?

Comment: @Zoso Because C is just an example of a class inheriting from A and B both. There could be a D, E, F, ... I didn't want to create an intermediary class X inheriting from both A and B that my C D E F etc inherit from, because that class would basically be completely empty and only serve as a wrapper, which is kind of ugly. Plus, C, D, E and F don't necessarily have much to do with one another semantically, apart from inheriting from the same classes.

Comment: why do you consider an empty class ugly? If it servers its purpose and needs no code to achieve that, I cannot see any bad about that

Answer (score 0):

The way to do a sidecast is with a `dynamic_cast`. (You can even put this to the test. Head over to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) and search for "sidecast". There is exactly one hit.) The `dynamic_cast` will use its dynamic magic to ensure that the pointed-to object does in fact inherit from the new class (e.g. `B`) and dynamically determine what offset needs to be added to the pointer to perform the sidecast.

I would not call the `dynamic_cast` approach "ugly", but I do find it lacking in elegance. Acceptable, but not highly desired. I would prefer a more structured approach, given the assertion that the objects in question are  known to inherit from both `A` and `B`. (If it weren't for this assertion, `dynamic_cast` would appear to be potentially the correct approach.)

You have a container somewhere that holds objects known to inherit from both `A` and `B`. Is there a name for such objects? If so, that could be the basis for a new class, call it `AB`, that inherits from `A` and `B`. It might do nothing other than inherit from those two classes, but that can still serve a useful role in your container. If your container were to hold pointers to `AB`, then the container would self-document that all elements must derive from both `A` and `B`. In addition, there would be no need to check types dynamically, nor to handle a failure to sidecast. The compiler would enforce that an object has to derive from both `A` and `B` to be added to the container in the first place. Furthermore, there would be no need to dynamically calculate an offset, as that offset gets baked into `AB`. The overall result is cleaner code with more checks made at compile-time. I would prefer this solution.

---

A comment from the OP makes the assertion that this proposed `AB` would "basically be completely empty and only serve as a wrapper, which is kind of ugly." I disagree with the "ugly" part, although I do not seek to argue that such an opinion is wrong. I will, though, point out that there is precedent. As far as the public interface goes, [`std::iostream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) is basically completely empty and only serves as a wrapper for `std::istream` combined with `std::ostream`. Its role is similar to what I propose for `AB`. You are welcome to consider `std::iostream` ugly, but it is undeniably standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the addresses of `A` and `B` in your objects will be the same, or even that the difference between these addresses will be the same for all `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`. This implies that you need to supply additional data for each element of the vector, which will tell how to get a pointer to base classes A and B.

`dynamic_cast` extracts this additional data from the virtual table (assuming that the compiler implements RTTI via the virtual table).

Pros:

- No memory overhead.
- Scalable, in case you want to add a third, fourth, etc base classes.

Cons:

- Requires RTTI.
- `dynamic_cast` can be somewhat slow (if it's implemented via traversing the class hierarchy).

Possible alternatives:

### 1. Adapter

```
class Adapter {
 public:
  template<class C>
  /* implicit */ Adapter(C* pointer):
    pointer_a_(pointer),
    pointer_b_(pointer) {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<A, C> && std::is_base_of_v<B, C>,
                      "C should be derived from both A and B.");
  }

  A* getA() const { return pointer_a_; }
  B* getB() const { return pointer_b_; }

 private:
  A* pointer_a_ = nullptr;
  B* pointer_b_ = nullptr;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Adapter> my_vector;
  C1 c1;
  C2 c2;
  my_vector.emplace_back(&c1);
  my_vector.emplace_back(&c2);
  for (Adapter& elem : my_vector) {
    elem->getA()->foo();
    elem->getB()->bar();
  }
}
```

Pros:

- Doesn't require RTTI.
- Fast.
- Can ensure at compile time that the objects in the vector are actually derived from both `A` and `B`.

Cons:

- Memory overhead (per object) from the additional pointer.

### 2. Add a virtual function B* A::getB().

```
class A {
 public:
  // Return this (casted to B*), or nullptr if the dynamic object is not derived from B.
  virtual B* getB() { return nullptr; }
  // ...
};

class C : public FooWhichInheritsB, public A {
 public:
  B* getB() override { return this; }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<A*> my_vector;
  C1 c1;
  C2 c2;
  my_vector.emplace_back(&c1);
  my_vector.emplace_back(&c2);
  for (A* elem : my_vector) {
    elem->foo();
    elem->getB()->bar();
  }
}
```

Pros:

- Doesn't require RTTI.
- No memory overhead (per object).
- Calling the virtual function `getB()` is faster than performing `dynamic_cast`.

Cons:

- Calling the virtual function `getB()` is slower than simply reading the `pointer_b_` member in the `Adapter` implementation.
- You need to remember to override `getB()` in each `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, ...

### 3. Introduce a common base class AB

```
class AB : public A, public B {};
class C : public AB { /* ... */ };
class D : public AB { /* ... */ };
```

Pros:

- Doesn't require RTTI.
- No memory overhead (per object).
- Even faster than Adapter.

Cons:

- Adds a constraint on the class hierarchy - you can no longer add an object of the type `class Foo : public A2, public B {};` (where `A2` is derived from `A`) to the vector.